# new, delete, Objective-C++, and leaks

Tags: objective-c

I'm adding functionality to an existing Cocoa application written mostly in Objective-C.  I have to use an existing c++ class in the class I'm writing, so the new class is Objective-C++.  Furthermore, I've had to write a method on the c++ class that temporarily uses a buffer.  So my c++ method is something like

```
(void) myMethod{
   int8_t* bffr = new int8_t[length];
   // use the buffer
   delete [] bffr;
}
```

I instantiate the c++ class in my .mm file, and try to carry on.  The problem is that the application crashes.  However, if I comment out the `delete`, the app does not crash, but Instruments reports a leak associated with this method.  I presume that the Objective-C memory management is getting bolluxed up.  How can I resolve this catch-22?

BTW, I get the same result using malloc and get_temporary_buffer.

Comment: It's quite possible there is an issue with your 'use the buffer' code, please show us what it does.

Comment: +1 @JoshuaWeinberg if your buffer is affected to a non-copied ObjectiveC object, it can't be safely deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must free the memory you allocated and do so at the right time - only after the time that no other code will ever attempt to access that piece of memory.

Comment: Argh.  I've looked at that `use the buffer` code for a couple of hours and thanks to this reply I notice that I've overwritten `bffr`.  Fixed.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried enabling the memory debugging features in Xcode to track down the source of the crash?

(Edit Scheme > Debug > Memory Mgmt, tick all boxes)

Cheers,
Jay